# View loaded from xib file and added to scrollView draws over it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xib

I have scrollView set for horizontal scrolling (paging enabled, ...).
If i create UiViews in code and add them to scrollView everything works ok.
Example:

```
//second page
CGRect frame2;
frame2.origin.x = myScrollView.frame.size.width;
frame2.origin.y = 0;
frame2.size = myScrollView.frame.size;

UIImage *tutImage2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialScreen2.png"];
UIImageView *tutorialImage2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tutImage2];
tutorialImage2.frame=tutImageFrame;

UIView *subview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
subview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[subview2 addSubview:tutorialImage2];
[myScrollView addSubview:subview2];
```

The problem is with views loaded from xib, because they draw over scrollView (eventhough their frame is set to height smaller than full screen).
Example:

```
//third page
CGRect frame3;
frame3.origin.x = myScrollView.frame.size.width*2;
frame3.origin.y = 0;
frame3.size = myScrollView.frame.size;
dashView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DashboardView"owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
dashView.frame=frame3;
[myScrollView addSubview:dashView];
```

I tried setting my view's simulated metrics size to freeform and retina 4inch and it didnt help. I also turned off autolayout (i dont use it in my xib) but it also didnt help.

Any idea?